# Implicit conversion to bool for std::exeption_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing some code that necessitates my caching an exception.

Please consider

```
int main()
{
    std::exception_ptr ex;
    bool b = ex;
}
```

This doesn't compile due to `ex` not being convertible to a `bool` type. My current workaround is to write

```
bool b = !!ex;
```

or even

```
bool b = ex ? true : false;
```

The first way is ugly, the second one a tautology surely. I'm starting to blame the compiler (MSVC2015). Two things:

1. Is there a better way of checking if `ex` has been set to an exception?
2. (Related) Do I need to initialise `ex` in some way?

Comment: @Downvoter: I'm sorry if this question offends you. If there is a way I can appease you then do please share your wisdom.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr

Comment: Yes I have. But I don't understand why using `!!` works, along with the conditional. What am I missing?

Comment: "A default-constructed std::exception_ptr is a null pointer; it does not point to an exception object." from @NathanOliver link addresses (2) in an obvious way. Come on, you're a 3k user, surely you can read technical stuff by now? Minus one for that. Otherwise the question is a good one IMHO.

Comment: You can use `bool b(ex);` or `bool b{ex};` if you really want to store that result in `bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr).

The implicit conversion is prohibited, but an explicit one is not.

> std::exception_ptr is not implicitly convertible to any arithmetic, enumeration, or pointer type. It is contextually convertible to bool, and will evaluate to false if it is null, true otherwise.

Hence it works when you explicitly convert the expression, but not when you attempt to do so implicitly, i.e. in the `bool` *copy-initialization*.

A better solution is to initialise the `bool` directly:

```
bool b{ex};
```

Your P45 is in the post; hopefully you'll consult documentation in your next job. ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, the syntax `bool b{ex}`  in this case is the same as `bool b(ex)` and even `bool b = static_cast<bool>(ex);`. At their core all of them invoke the `explicit operator bool()` conversion operator on the exception_ptr class.

Comment: @Johannes: Same result. Technically not equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The type `std::exception_ptr` is a nullable, which means that when it is default constructed as you have done it is a null value by default. Because this is a typedef and is not *necessarily* a raw pointer, it can not be assigned to a bool directly as this would be implicitly converting the type.

You can check to see if it has been set as you have done, or you can do so a bit more cleanly by using `nullptr`, or explicitly casting it to a boolean:

```
std::exception_ptr e;
bool isNull = false;

if(e == nullptr)
  isNull = true;
```

Explicit casting:

```
std::exception_ptr e;
bool isNull = static_cast<bool>(e);
```